# How to find the probability density function of a random variable that is related to another random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, density-function

[image: question 36 of GATE EC 2023]

I found a similar question already answered here: [Find CDF of random variable which depends on other variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2105218/find-cdf-of-random-variable-which-depends-on-other-variable)
Our goal is to find $f_Y$ (the PDF) which is the derivative of $F_Y$ (the CDF).

$X$ is a random variable distributed as $N(0,1)$, thus the PDF is:

$f_X(x) = \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

While the CDF is:
$F_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{- \infty}^{x}e^{-t^2/2}\,dt$

The support of $Y$ is $[-1, 1]$.
Clearly:

$P(Y = -1) = P(X \leq -2)$

$P(Y = 0) = P(-1 \leq X \leq 1)$

$P(Y = 1) = P(X \geq 2)$

Finally:

$P(-1 \lt Y \lt 0) = P(-2 \lt X \lt -1)$

$P(0 \lt Y \lt 1) = P(1 \lt X \lt 2)$

Though I have managed to break apart the CDF of $Y$, I'm unsure how to simplify these further. The CDF of $X$ is very complicated unlike in the question I've linked above.

The question is borrowed from GATE EC 2023.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is totally unnecessary to perform any detailed computations.

Assuming $\delta$ represents the Dirac delta function centered at $0$, we can immediately see from the graph that $Y$ is a mixed discrete-continuous random variable with discrete probability masses at $Y \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$.  Although the figure does not actually show whether the event $|Y| > 1$ has positive probability, we can infer from the location of these masses that the probability density of $Y$ must have delta functions at these locations.  Choices (A) and (D) are missing the one at $y = 0$; choices (C) and (D) are missing the ones at $y = \pm 1$.  Only choice (B) contains all three, so this must be the best answer.

However, as I have pointed out, what we can see of the graph of $h$ does not exclude the possibility that $h(X)$ may take on values outside the interval $[-1,1]$, so for instance, that there might be an interval for which $h(X) = 2$.  It might be vaguely *implied* that for all $X \ge 2$ that $h(X) = 1$, and that for $X \le -2$, that $h(X) = -1$, but if this is not the case, then choice (B) could also be incorrect.  But from what information we can see in the figure, the other choices are *necessarily* incorrect.

Comment: How did you spot the "discrete probability masses" at $-1, 0, 1$? What should I be looking for? I am not familiar with mixed discrete-continuous random variables.

Comment: @McSuperbX1 When you look at the plot of $h$, there are intervals where $h$ is constant.  The value of $h(X)$ where it is constant will correspond to discrete probability masses for $Y$.  So for instance, $$\Pr[Y = 0] = \Pr[h(X) = 0] = \Pr[-1 \le X \le 1],$$ and since this has positive probability, $Y$ will have a discrete mass at $0$.  However, $$\Pr[Y = 1/2] = \Pr[h(X) = 1/2] = \Pr[X = 3/2] = 0$$ because $X$ is a continuous random variable.  So $Y$ will have a density at $1/2$, but not a probability mass.

Comment: I think this is a satisfactory answer to the original question, I should go and read up on mixed discrete-continuous random variables perhaps then I'll be able to better appreciate your answer. Thanks. @heropup

Comment: @McSuperbX1 Here is a link to more information:  https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_3_1_mixed.php (disclaimer:  I found this link through a web search; I am not affiliated with the author of that website.)  Another link:  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/res-6-012-introduction-to-probability-spring-2018/resources/mixed-random-variables/